# ATL & COM - Multiple servers, one binary?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com, atl

I have two COM DLLs. Both of which implement ATL::CAtlDllModuleT<>. From my understanding, this class does the dirty work of registering and unregistering the COM objects. Is there a way to merge these two into one?

```
class CFoo : public ATL::CAtlDllModuleT< CFoo >
{
public :
    DECLARE_LIBID(LIBID_FooLib)
    DECLARE_REGISTRY_APPID_RESOURCEID(IDR_FOOINTERFACE, "{4E6823F7-230B-4D6C-9195-571B94B32859}")
};
```

The two projects that I have, one is the DLL and the other is the LIB (which gets linked in).

Answer (score 1):

See [OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3wywe%28VS.80%29.aspx) macro which creates a link between a clsid and your implementation object to provide support for the registration, initialisation, and creation of a class.  You just use the macro for each clsid you want from that exe/dll.

Comment: That's it? It seems a bit too easy for COM.

Comment: Oh, I'm sure there will be some other hell to help balance this appearing easy.  But that is it from my experience.

Comment: +1  @user318811: That should be enough - you just use that (or other equivalent) macro to tell ATL "I want to expose this class to registration" and if you have a typelib you have to mention it as well. Those macros populate a global map of stuff that needs to be registered when `DllRegisterServer()` is called. Maybe something will break, but ATL is shipped with sources, so you can debug those issues pretty easily.